# Align custom radio button with the top option content

Tags: html, css

I update this content with a new Jsfidle to show the issue with a max-width of 300px.

On a responsive design, I need to add the "span" tag in front of my radio buttons in order to align my input content with my custom checkbox background.

[To review the issue, reduce the windows browser until an option is displayed on two lines](http://jsfiddle.net/NFGHg/9/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sectors">
<li id="title"><p class="f32l32">Sectors</p></li>
<li>
    <label class="search-radio-button f15l18">
        <input value="61" name="sectors[]" type="radio" class="radio sectors-radio-button"> Built environment
        <span class="Built environment"></span>             
    </label>
</li>
            <li>
    <label class="search-radio-button f15l18">
        <input value="62" name="sectors[]" type="radio" class="radio sectors-radio-button"> Defence &amp; government
        <span class="Defence &amp; government"></span>              
    </label>
</li>
            <li>
    <label class="search-radio-button f15l18">
        <input value="63" name="sectors[]" type="radio" class="radio sectors-radio-button"> Manufacturing &amp; technology
        <span class="Manufacturing &amp; technology"></span>                
    </label>
</li>
            <li>
    <label class="search-radio-button f15l18">
        <input value="64" name="sectors[]" type="radio" class="radio sectors-radio-button"> Oil, energy &amp; mining
        <span class="Oil, energy &amp; mining"></span>              
    </label>
</li>
            <li>
    <label class="search-radio-button f15l18">
        <input value="65" name="sectors[]" type="radio" class="radio sectors-radio-button"> Transport
        <span class="Transport"></span>             
    </label>
</li>
            <li>
    <label class="search-radio-button f15l18">
        <input value="66" name="sectors[]" type="radio" class="radio sectors-radio-button"> Utilities &amp; infrastructure
        <span class="Utilities &amp; infrastructure"></span>                
    </label>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
   ul#sectors, ul#locations {
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 2.5%;
}

#detail-search-container li#title {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 5%;
padding-top: 6%;
}

#detail-search-container li {
min-height: 20px;
width: 50%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}

#detail-search-container li label {
padding-left: 20px;
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 20%;
width: 80%;
}

.search-radio-button span {
width: 20px;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
float: left;
background: url("http://satafx.com/img/radio.gif");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: -3px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: -20%;
}

.search-radio-button input {
display: none;
}

.search-radio-button input:checked + span, .class_checkbox.checked {
background-position: 0px -20px;
background-position: 0px -26px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some cosmetic changes to your CSS as i'm mentioning below with comments.

1) Remove `background-position:`

```
.search-radio-button input:checked + span, .class_checkbox.checked {
   background-position: 0px -20px;
   background-position: 0px -26px; // remove this
}
```

2) Set margin-top and left acordingly

```
.search-radio-button span {
   width: 20px;
   width: 22px;
   height: 22px;
   float: left;
   background: url("http://satafx.com/img/radio.gif");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-top: 0; //change this
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: -9%; //change this
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NFGHg/4/)

[**<kbd>Updated Fiddle</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/NFGHg/10/)

Hope you want like this!

Comment: Thanks, however, the input text need to be align with my custom checkboxes. I update my Jsfidle link

Comment: @Romain I've updated my fiddle in answer! check again

Comment: Excellent =)
 lol, I really need to sleep. Thanks for your fast and clear answer.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, I just have to put the span before the input...

```
<li>
    <label class="search-radio-button f15l18">
        <span class="Built environment"></span>             
        <input value="61" name="sectors[]" type="radio" class="radio sectors-radio-button"> Built environment
    </label>
</li>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: I you do so, the alignment is perfect however the custom checkbox will never be checked.